# MySQLi Inconsistent Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to enter data into my MySQL database using the following query

```
UPDATE `Customer Table` SET `ID`=$ID, `First name`='$FirstName',`Last name`='$LastName',`Home phone number`=$HomePhoneNumber,`Mobile phone number`=$MobilePhoneNumber,`House number`=$HouseNumber,`House name`='$HouseName',`Street name`='$StreetName',`Town name`='$TownName',`Post code`='$PostCode' ,`Notes`='$Notes' WHERE ID=$ID
```

This is working fine when I'm calling it from one PHP file but not working when I'm calling it from an API PHP file.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`House number`=0,`House name`='43',`Street name`='Westbury',`Town name`='We' at line 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`House number`=0,`House name`='3',`Street name`='Close',`Town name`='Thorn' at line 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`House number`=0,`House name`='flat',`Street name`='2 road',`Town ' at line 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`House number`=0,`House name`='39',`Street name`='valley',`Town name`='',`' at line 1
```

Can anyone see where the error is as I'm struggling to find it. All of the data types are correct from what I can see.

Thanks in advance, Luke.

Comment: Print out the query after the variable substitution and the answer will probably be obvious.

Comment: The API I'm creating is working with an android application. Added the tag now as I though at some point I might need to post some of the code form it

Comment: This is a lot easier with `prepared queries` ;-/ Or a 'database access layer'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It seems that your variable `$MobilePhoneNumber` contains string part within it something like **`+`**

```
"UPDATE `Customer Table` SET `ID` = '$ID', `First name` = '$FirstName',
`Last name`= '$LastName',`Home phone number`= '$HomePhoneNumber',
`Mobile phone number` = '$MobilePhoneNumber',`House number` = '$HouseNumber',
`House name`='$HouseName',`Street name`='$StreetName',`Town name`='$TownName',
`Post code`='$PostCode',`Notes`='$Notes' WHERE ID=$ID"
```

Comment: Nope, just an integer. it's only containing 0 at the moment for most contacts as the data was not collected in the system in exported the data from

Comment: [**Check This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206543/mysqli-inconsistent-syntax-error/31206881#comment50414842_31206543)

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff suggestions was best, $MobilePhoneNumber was not being read from my XML file.`+ "<MobilePhoneNumber>" + MobileNumber + "</MobileNumber>` was being written instead of `+ "<MobilePhoneNumber>" + MobileNumber + "</MobilePhoneNumber>`